Vcenter adds a huge space
I'd like to center picture on the math axis, vcenter is supposed to be precisely for this purpose, but it adds a huge space:

any idea why?
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
I'd like to center picture on the math axis, like:
\begin{align*}
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height+.55ex\relax}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}} = 42
\end{align*}
Vcenter is supposed to be precisely for this purpose, but it adds a huge space:
\begin{align*}
  \vcenter{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}} = 42
\end{align*}
\end{document}


I think the question could be the other way round --- why does raisebox remove the space introduced with width=3cm...  ??

Why \vcenter? It's not as straightforward as you think.
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

I'd like to center picture on the math axis, like:
\begin{equation*}
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height+.55ex\relax}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}} = 42
\end{equation*}
Vcenter is supposed to be precisely for this purpose, but it's not. In math mode
you can use \texttt{gathered}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{gathered}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\end{gathered} = 42
\end{equation*}
or \texttt{tabular}, in all situations
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\end{tabular} = 42
\end{equation*}
But the simplest way is to use \texttt{adjustbox}
\begin{equation*}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image-a} = 42
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


If you insist in \vcenter, it should be
\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}}

so the \hbox won't initiate horizontal mode, which would cause the \vcenter to be as wide as the current \hsize (with the indent at the beginning, by the way).

Thanks! Note also the \adjustbox{valign=c}{…} to align arbitrary text (e.g. a tikzpicture).

\vcenter makes a vertical box as wide as its content.
You have
\vcenter{\includegraphics

which is like
\vcenter{x}

so the x (or \includegraphics starts a paragraph so invokes TeX's line breaker to make lines \hsize (which is currently \textwidth)) wide.
\vcenter isn't suported syntax in a latex document, the latex ways would be
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\includegraphics{..}\end{tabular}

or use adjustbox package and
\includegraphics[valign=m]{\includegraphics{...}}

